# Where can I get Ubuntu templates/themes for Joomla or Wordpress?

Tags: themes, wordpress, joomla

May you suggest me how to recreate/build a template/theme similar to askubuntu for a Joomla/Wordpress web site please?

Answer (score 1):

The community maintains Ubuntu themes for some web frameworks. You can find themes for Wordpress, Drupal, and Django here:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-community-webthemes

But there does not appear to be a Joomla theme.

Comment: Is this still developed? Wordpress theme for example?